# AngularUI bootstrap popover issue with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, popover

I am trying to implement popover functionality using Bootstrap & angularJS but popup doesn't seem to work & i don't get any errors either. Any help would be highly appreciated

```html
<button popover-template="'popover.html'"
        popover-placement="top"
        popover-trigger="click"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-default">
  Mouse over me
</button>
```

I added ngAnimate & ui.bootstrap as a dependent to my angular application. Here is the code for the popover.html

```
<label class="Label">
    test
</label>
```

It doesn't acually create a popover on click & doesn't create an error message either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the directive is `uib-popover-template`:

```
<button ̶p̶o̶p̶o̶v̶e̶r̶-̶t̶e̶m̶p̶l̶a̶t̶e̶=̶"̶'̶p̶o̶p̶o̶v̶e̶r̶.̶h̶t̶m̶l̶'̶"̶
        uib-popover-template="'popover.html'"
        popover-placement="top"
        popover-trigger="click"
        type="button"
        class="btn btn-default">
  Mouse over me
</button>
```

For more information, see

- [Angular UI Bootstrap Directive API and Demo - Popover](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!popover)

For more information, see

Comment: Is there a minimum angularJS & bootstrap version needed for popover to work?. I am guessing that may be the problem as i have created a basic web app & tried to implement the functionality &  that seems to work but when i start implementing in existing application it doesn't seem to work

Comment: AngularUI Bootstrap works with Bootstrap 3. It has not been updated to work with Bootstrap 4. If you want to see if Angular UI Bootstrap works with older versions of AngularJS, take the demo and experiment for yourself. I personnally recommend using the latest version of AngularJS for the security upgrades.